# Wrong date while using date.setTime() with date/time format by JSON data

Tags: java, datetime-format, android-date

I got a date/time format data from
http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/geojson/all/hour

here's a quote of data:

```
"properties":{
    "mag":0.5,
    "place":"123km NNW of Talkeetna, Alaska",
    "time":1343795877,
    "tz":-480,
    "url":"/earthquakes/eventpage/ak10523664",
    "felt":null,
    "cdi":null,
    "mmi":null,
    "alert":null,
    "status":"AUTOMATIC",
    "tsunami":null,
    "sig":"4",
    "net":"ak",
    "code":"10523664",
    "ids":",ak10523664,",
    "sources":",ak,",
    "types":",general-link,general-link,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,"
},
```

but when I use:

```
Date date1 = new Date();
date1.setTime("1343795877");
```

the result is: Fri Jan 16 13:16:35 GMT+00:00 1970
but the correct date is Wednesday, August 01, 2012 04:37:57 UTC (from CSV version of the same website)

How can I get the correct time??

Comment: changing timezone will not help you.. how can that.. just think timezone only have difference in hours not in years :P

Comment: @Abhishekbhutra Hay, I guess it depends on where you live ;) - good point though, sorry :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number "1343795877" is [unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) - time in seconds that elapsed since 1970.

You need to multiply it by 1000 because it is time in **seconds** and Date constructor takes milliseconds. So this will do the magic:

```
Date d = new Date(1343795877*1000);
```

You can use online [UNIX to Date converter](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm) to check it.

Bear in mind that UNIX time is in UTC and it does not mimic user timezone - so you will need to apply your timezone.

I suggest you to work with [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) it is really handy.

Here is an example of the conversion.:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1343795877*1000);
dt.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("UTC"));
```

EDIT:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss, SSS [z]");
formatter.print(dt);
```

Comment: how to remove the "T" and ".000Z"??

Comment: You need to use a propper timezone and apply formatter (see my edit)

Answer (score 1):

First of all your syntax is wrong. Date have no method such as `date.setTime(String)`. Its `date.setTime(Long)` which takes `milliseconds as argument`. And what you are getting is `seconds` so just multiply it by 1000 to get correct date. So your solution is `date1.setTime(1343795877000L);`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here its simply :

```
new Date(epochTime * epochFormat) // '1343795877' this time format is known as epoch time
```

`epochTime` is time of long type eg. **1343795877L**
`epochFormat` is **1000** if `epochTime` is in **seconds** else **1** if in **milliseconds**

In your case its in **seconds** so multiply by **1000**

I think you should also use `SimpleDateFormatter` to **format** your date :

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd-MMM-yy", Locale.ENGLISH); // date format and locale you want to use
dateFormat.setTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"); // can have your time zone
String date = dateFormat.format(new Date(epochTime * epochFormat));
```

for **date formats** look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)